# Set focus to a element of a list

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have the next code:

```js
          {tropes.map((trope, id) => (
            <DescriptionOfTropeInUse
              key={id}
              tropeName={trope.name}
            />
          ))}
          <DescriptionOfTropeInUse
            tropeName={newTropeName}
            onChangeTrope={addTrope}
          />
```

The idea is that when someone starts to write on the last element of my list a new element is added to the list, whatever thing that the user was written is move to the new element **and the focus is change to it**, the user would only will notice that a new field is create under the one where him is typing in but don't know that the whole field was moved.

But I'm having problems to make ReactJS understand my request to move the focus, I tried this code:

```js
autoFocus={tropeOnFocus === id}
```

but I don't work nor did it make an error, Also, I want to use **functional components**, I prefer not complicate me with classes.
So, how can I accomplish to make ReactJS set the focus to the last element of my list(or an arbitrary one)?

Edit:
This is `DescriptionOfTropeInUse` component:

```js
const DescriptionOfTropeInUse = ({
  onChangeName,
  onChangeDescription,
  tropeName,
  tropeDescription,
  autoFocus,
}) => {
  return (
    <Grid container>
      <Grid item xs={3}>
        <TextField
          id="name"
          label="Name"
          onChange={onChangeName}
          value={tropeName}
          autoFocus={autoFocus}
        />
      </Grid>
      <Grid item xs={9}>
        <TextField
          id="description"
          label="Description"
          onChange={onChangeDescription}
          value={tropeDescription}
        />
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  );
};
```

This is just a two field group component, I only want to focus on the first `TextField` component, so the user can continue typing the name without notice anything, Thank you

Comment: You would need to provide a little more context. What is `DescriptionOfTropeInUse`. How does it look like?

Comment: I just edited the question, thank you